# rails-3.2.14.rc2,spork 0.9.2,watchr-0.7 and rspec 3.1.0 = uninitialized constant RSpec::Core::CommandLine (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rspec-rails, spork, watchr

*****rails_helper.rb*****

require 'spec_helper'

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|

config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

end

****spec_helper.rb****

require 'rubygems'

require "spork"

Spork.prefork do

ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'

require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", **FILE**)

require 'rspec/rails'

require "capybara/rspec"

require "email_spec"

require "selenium-webdriver"

require "webrat"

require "webrat/core/matchers"

require "rspec/autorun"

include Webrat::Methods

RSpec.configure do |config|

config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

config.order = "random"

config.before(:suite) do

```
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
```

end

config.before(:each) do

```
  DatabaseCleaner.start

end

config.after(:each) do

  DatabaseCleaner.clean

end
```

end

end

Spork.each_run do

require "factory_girl_rails"

RSpec.configure do |config|

```
config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
```

end

end

Webrat.configure do |config|

config.mode = :rack

end

Comment: see https://github.com/sporkrb/spork/pull/255#issuecomment-56517895

Comment: Thanks gotva for letting me know the solution :)